# xcodebuild internal error for Xcode 4.6.3

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I updated Xcode to 4.6 on Lion, and I deleted /Developer directory.

Then, when I tried to execute xcodebuild, I got this error.

```
xcodebuild 
xcodebuild: error: developer tools not installed; download from http://developer.apple.com
```

I soft-linked the xcodebuild inside the Xcode app:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild /usr/bin/xcodebuild
```

However this time, I got internal error.

```
> === BUILD NATIVE TARGET gv OF PROJECT grapevine WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Debug) === Check dependencies
> 
> ** INTERNAL ERROR: Uncaught exception ** Exception: *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil Stack:   0 
> 0x00007fff915d8f3a __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)   1 
> 0x00007fff91081d5e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)   2 
> 0x00007fff9157fab8 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] (in
> CoreFoundation)   3  0x0000000103732337 -[XCDependencyCommand
> createStartedCommandInvocation] (in DevToolsCore)   4 
> 0x00000001037e081b -[Xcode3BuildTask main] (in DevToolsCore)   5 
> 0x00007fff933126b4 -[__NSOperationInternal start] (in Foundation)   6 
> 0x00007fff93325912 ____NSOQSchedule_block_invoke_2 (in Foundation)   7
> 0x00007fff8ef7ca82 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in
> libdispatch.dylib)   8  0x00007fff8ef7d961 _dispatch_worker_thread2
> (in libdispatch.dylib)   9  0x00007fff909f23da _pthread_wqthread (in
> libsystem_c.dylib)  10  0x00007fff909f3b85 start_wqthread (in
> libsystem_c.dylib)
```

Abort trap: 6

What might be wrong? I have xcode 4.6.3.

```
xcodebuild -version
Xcode 4.6.3
Build version 4H1503
```

Comment: Try deleting that soft link and re-installing Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall didn't solve the issue, emptying the trash (and preferably reboot) removed this error message.